# Why does `color` override `position` in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, position-dodge

I'm having a problem whereby a setup that works for position-dodging
gets disabled if I specify an alternative color. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(emmeans)
noise.lm = lm(noise ~ size * type * side, data = auto.noise)

emmip(noise.lm, side * size ~ type, CIs = TRUE,
      CIarg = list(lwd = 1, alpha = 0.5, linetype = "solid"))
```

This produces the following plot
[image: plot with automatic colors]

Note that the confidence intervals (vertical bars) are offset from one another.
If, however, I do exactly the same thing but add a color specification:

```
emmip(noise.lm, side * size ~ type, CIs = TRUE,
      CIarg = list(lwd = 1, alpha = 0.5, linetype = "solid", color = "gray"))
```

Then I get this result

[image: plot with specified colors]

... and the offsetting seems to have been disabled. Why is that
and how do I avoid it?

More details: the `CIarg` argument in `emmip()` is used to specify additional
arguments to the code that produces the confidence intervals. The relevant code within `emmeans::emmip()` is

```
    if (CIs) {
        CIarg$mapping = ggplot2::aes_(ymin = ~LCL, ymax = ~UCL)
        CIarg$position = pos
        grobj = grobj + do.call(ggplot2::geom_linerange, CIarg)
    }
```

where `grobj` is the plot object being created, and (earlier in the code) `pos`
was created via

```
    pos = ggplot2::position_dodge(width = ifelse(CIs|PIs, dodge, 0)) # use dodging if CIs
```

where `dodge = 0.1` (default argument value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the grouping and hence the dodging is determined by the color aesthetic. Using `color="grey"` you override the grouping and the lineranges for the CIs no longer get dodged. I don't see any option to avoid that, only one to fix that by fixing the mapping, i.e. adding the `group` aes to the `geom_linerange` like so:

Note: `tvar` is the variable mapped on the color `aes`.

```r
library(emmeans)
noise.lm = lm(noise ~ size * type * side, data = auto.noise)

p <- emmip(noise.lm, side * size ~ type, CIs = TRUE,
      CIarg = list(lwd = 1, alpha = 0.5, linetype = "solid", color = "grey"))

p$layers[[3]]$mapping <- ggplot2::aes_(ymin = ~LCL, ymax = ~UCL, group = ~tvar)

p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Following this suggestion, I added `group = ~tvar` to the initial aesthetics for `grobj`, and that seems to solve the problem! Now I need to stop and think and try to understand how this all fits together (and what I broke by doing this).